# Unable to fetch Userid from ADO through MS Graph or Powershell output

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to get the Users and their projects belong to from ADO using MyPAT and Powershell

```
$connectionToken = "<PAT>"
$base64AuthInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$ProjectsBelongUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/adient/_apis/userentitlements/{userid}?api-version=5.1-preview.2" 

Write-Host "URL: $ProjectsBelongUrl"

$UserEntitlements = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ProjectsBelongUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) })

$ProjectsList = $($Pipelines.projectEntitlements.projectRef.name | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)


Write-Host "User XX belog to which projects = $ProjectsList"
```

{userid} - In this place I was trying to get this from MS Graph using API request GET and the output text file does not contain userid for any of the user, only the PrincipalName, OriginID which is not useful in my code

Can anyone please provide a solution on how to fetch the userid and loop through the users to get all the users and their projects assigned from ADO to convert into an Excel?

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 for your reply. Can you please post that link which would be really helpful to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all users from ado assigned projects in a given scope.

Since the list of users may be large, results are returned in pages of users. If there are more results than can be returned in a single page, the result set will contain a continuation token for retrieval of the next set of results.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#examples

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have tried the same process to get the user ids but I was able to only fetch the text file from MS graph with Principal id's, Names, Origin id except the "userid's".